# Ripple Asset Fees

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways, ripple-transaction-fees, ripple-trust

How would you issue an asset with a fee and then have a customized fee structures once the asset starts trading? Such as Maker/Taker model or customized fees when transmitting the asset after the issue.  Where would details of that be in the Ripple docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find details about transfer fees on the Ripple Developer Center:

https://ripple.com/build/transfer-fees/

Comment: Is it possible to customize it depending on taking or adding liquidity? Example 20bps add, 30bps take.  Also, is it possible to have different rate structures dependent upon on who the user Is? User A may pay 20bps but charge user b 50bps.

Comment: No, you can't do that. The transfer rate is common for all issues from a given issuer.

Comment: @jmar42 The protocol doesn't support that directly. But you can set the transfer fee to your maximum fee and then issue rebates however you want.

Comment: That's a neat way of handling that, @DavidSchwartz.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically I would need some type of smart contracts made and if I want liquidity within the Ripple network, connect w Interledger?